# How to disable Thunderbird's internal web browser?

Tags: thunderbird

I don't remember how the program behaved on Windows, but on Linux pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> for a feed item (with a `Website` field) always opens the Thunderbird's internal browser, while *clicking* the URL launches my default browser (Firefox).

This damages my keyboard-centric workflow.

In the Thunderbird's config editor I've set both `network.protocol-handler.warn-external.http` and `network.protocol-handler.warn-external.https` to `true` and associated Firefox in the 'attachment' options ([reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20200827092647/https://www.lifewire.com/change-the-default-browser-in-thunderbird-2532751)). This made no difference I was able to notice.

Comment: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-subscribe-news-feeds-and-blogs, in the "Advanced Tips" section, mentions `rss.show.content-base` and `rss.message.loadWebPageOnSelect`.  It's been ages since I used TB for RSS but my notes say these entries helped me.  I cannot be 100% sure what you need is what I had at that time, but it can't hurt to try...

Comment: @sitaram: `rss.show.content-base` to `3` alone appears to have started loading websites in my default browser. While this doesn't *disable* the TB's web browser (which I'd prefer for security reasons) and the changelog for instance loads there, I consider the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Config Editor, set the `rss.show.content-base` property to `3`.

According to [the Mozilla Support page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-subscribe-news-feeds-and-blogs), the different values correspond to:

```
0 - open web page in new window
1 - open summary in new window
2 - toggle load summary and web page in message pane
3 - load web page in browser
```

Also, Thunderbird supports an additional action on the selection of a feed message with the setting `rss.message.loadWebPageOnSelect`:

```
0 - no action
1 - load web page in default browser
```

Comment: This answer came from [a comment on the question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/607697/13308#comment1135379_607697).